# Смена цвета картинки при наведении JS-CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Каким образом при помощи **JS или CSS плавно** сменить цвет картинки **на красный** при наведении мыши,
а после того как курсор покинет иконку, цвет картинки должен **плавно** возвращаться к своему родному цвету.

По задумке цвет не должен заливать весь блок и внутреннюю часть картинки,
цвет должен меняться только у черных полей(фигур) картинки.

**Вот такой результат по идее должен быть:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.icon {
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img class="icon" src=" https://i.ibb.co/YQGCtCv/2311.png">
```

⠀⠀

UPD: Благодаря архимагу Алексею Шиманскому удалось добиться желаемого результата,
но теперь пропала плавность перехода. **Как вернуть плавность перехода?**

```css
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.icon2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.icon:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/YQGCtCv/2311.png">
<img class="icon2" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WMcYq1/233.png">
```

Comment: Выбор не велик, или две картинки одинаковые разного цвета и при наведении одна затухает другая появляется,  Второй вариант Картинки нарисовать в формате SVG или Canvas и далее  менять при наведении

Comment: А что за способ про две картинки? Можно пожалуйста пример =)

Comment: Лучше уж тогда SVG... Скачай какой-нибудь редактор, советую `adobe illustrator`, как там рисовать найдешь кучу уроков... Любой поисковик тебе в помощь... Далее дело техники

Comment: В моём случае, чем Svg лучше png?

Comment: Никакой... Нарисуй как тебе угодно... Потом конвертируй в любой формат...

Comment: Поставлю вам плюсики в комменты за помощь =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить **[transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)**, а при `hover` указать что поменять.

```css
.icon {
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: 1.0s;
}


.icon:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<img class="icon" src=" https://i.ibb.co/YQGCtCv/2311.png">
```

---

Есть способ изменить именно цвет картинки через `filter` но он глючный и вроде не везде поддерживается

```css
.icon {
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s;
  
  
  filter: invert(0%) sepia(100%) saturate(14%) hue-rotate(273deg) brightness(104%) contrast(104%);
}


.icon:hover {
  
  filter: invert(11%) sepia(95%) saturate(7200%) hue-rotate(1deg) brightness(99%) contrast(109%);
}
```

```html
<img class="icon" src=" https://i.ibb.co/YQGCtCv/2311.png">
```

---

Тоже при первом появлении глючит

```css
.icon {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;  
  background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/YQGCtCv/2311.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


.icon:hover {  
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eGGn.png);  
}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```

Comment: Я пробовал такой метод, но он заливает цветом весь блок и внутреннюю часть картинки, а по идее цвет должен меняться только у черных полей(фигур) картинки. Вот, я даже картинку как пример желаемого результата загрузил сюда в тему.

Comment: Поставлю плюсик за потраченное время =)

Comment: а. не так понял вопрос. с img так нельзя сделать на сколько я знаю. с иконками типа бутстрапа - можно. svg можно ещё. а с img никак, только если две картинки делать

Comment: А что за способ про две картинки? Можно пожалуйста пример =)

Comment: Нарисовал пару примеров, но они немного глючные. Как сделать совсем плавные - не знай)

Comment: Лучшее отображение качества картинки у background-image(Css) или у тега img (Html) ?

Comment: На основе вашего кода, я создал код без бага первого появления, но теперь пропала плавность. Я этот код кинул в тему. Как вернуть плавность переходу? Посмотрите пожалуйста на код.

Comment: Кстати, это не глюк. Попробуйте свои предложенные методы на своём ПК, там глюка не будет. Думаю это глючит на сайте редактор воспроизведения кода =)

Comment: Еще раз благодарю за проделанный труд, ставлю вам везде плюсики =)

Comment: @Домик " на своём ПК, там глюка не будет. Думаю это глючит на сайте" --- понятно. интересно. попробую бывает и такое, вполне)